# what are the tensor rule for canceling indices in the same tensor variable?

Tags: tensors

**what are the tensor rule for canceling indices in the same tensor variable?**

let's say I have a tensor:

$\Huge V^{rs}_{trs}$

textbook says this tensor is equal to:

$\Huge V^{rs}_{trs} = V_{t}$

Which I could believe because it looks like the same letters cancel each other out, but then again. i'm not really sure what's happening here...what's the general rule for canceling out indices on the same variable?  can the indices with the same index variables be in any position in the upper and lower, and if they match can you cancel them out, or do they need to be in specific slots to  cancelling the upper and lower indices of the same term to work?

I'm just going to hit this question with a brute force hammar:

true or false? $\huge V^{ij}_{i} = V^j$

true or false? $\huge V^{ji}_{i} = V^j$

true or false? $\huge V_{ji}^{i} = V_j$

true or false? $\huge V_{ij}^{i} = V_j$

true or false? $\huge V_{i}^{i} = V$

true or false? $\huge V_{ii}^j = V^j$

true or false? $\huge V^{ii}_j = V_j$

all you need to do is copy and paste this section and answer true or false.
Then I will understand the rule.  Thanks.

Comment: They aren't canceling the indices. They are actually summing them out. These are called "contractions" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction

Comment: A pedestrian example of a contraction would be $A_i^i$ which is the trace of the matrix $A_i^j$.

Comment: can you contract any index slot with any other index slot in the same tensor variable regardless if its upper or lower index?

Comment: what about all the "non-pedestrian" examples listed... are they all true or are there some exceptions?

Comment: No, unless you have an inner product allowing you to identify your underlying vector space with its dual. Such an isomorphism (between vector space and dual - which is essentially the same thing as specifying an inner product) allows you to raise and lower indices.

Comment: Also, when someone writes $V_{ij}^i=V_j$. This is a definition. We are defining a new lower rank tensor by contracting out two indices from a higher rank tensor much in the same  way the trace of a matrix is not the matrix itself but instead is some summary information about it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is true on all accounts.  But, there's a caveat... I'll illustrate one example without any deleted steps to show what's happening:

Let's assume this tensor is over $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$\Huge V^{ii}_j = V^{11}_j + V^{22}_j + V^{33}_j = \tilde{V}_j$

Here I'm using the tilde to indicate that $\huge \tilde{V}$ is a different tensor that is the sum of three terms.  However, at this point we drop the use of the tilde for this purpose, instead, we implicitly see that:

**any tensor with different tensor ranks in the numerator and denominator is implicitly a different variable even enough though the base letter is the same**. thus:

$\Huge V^{ii}_j = V_j$

it would be just as vaild to write the contraction this way as well:

$\Huge V^{ii}_j = W_j$

Both are equivalent, but reusing the same letter saves letters and keeps track of where a tensor variable came from.... its a type of "overloading" of variable names...

---

Here are the rules for contraction.

**Contraction of (2,2) tensor**

Suppose $\huge A^{i_1~ i_2}_{j_1~ j_2}$ is a tensor.

Assuming $\mathbb{R}^n$, The contraction of A with respect to $i_2$ and $j_1$, is given by setting $i_2 = j_i = u$ and evaluating:

$\huge A^{i_1~ u}_{u~ j_2}  = A^{i_1~ 1}_{1~ j_2} + A^{i_1~ 2}_{2~ j_2}  + A^{i_1~ 3}_{3~ j_2} =\tilde{A}^{i_1}_{j_2}$

in going from A to $\tilde{A}$ , contravariant rank is reduced by 1, and covariant rank reduced by 1. Thus:

contracting a (2,2) tensors results in a (1,1) tensor.

**Contraction of (p, q) tensor**

Suppose S is a (p, q) tensor such that $\huge S \equiv \bigg(S^{~i_1~ i_2~ \dots ~i_{\Large p}}_{~j_1~ j_2~ \dots~ j_{\Large q}}\bigg)$.  The contraction of S with respect to a contravariant index $i_f$ and a covariant index $j_g$ is given by setting $\huge i_f = j_g = u$ and evaluating:

$\huge S^{~i_1~\dots~u~\dots~i_{\Large p}}_{~j_1~\dots~u~\dots~j_{\Large q}} = \tilde{S}^{~i_1~\dots~i_{\Large p}}_{~j_1~\dots~j_{\Large q}}$

$\tilde{S}$ is now a (p-1, q-1) tensor.

contracting a (p,q) tensors results in a (p-1,q-1) tensor

Comment: if you beleive wikipedia, it says: " contraction on a pair of indices that are either both contravariant or both covariant is not possible in general. However, in the presence of an inner product (also known as a metric) g, such contractions are possible. One uses the metric to raise or lower one of the indices, as needed, and then one uses the usual operation of contraction. The combined operation is known as metric"... not sure i understand, because i just showed you can contract it... unless there's some reason why that's not valid...

Comment: You can contract that way, its just that the result is generally not a tensor when contracting a pair of covariant indexes, or a pair of contravariant indexes.   To remain a tensor 100% of the time you first need to use a metric tensor to juggle one of the contracting indexes to to be opposite of the other before performing contraction.  that's why they usually ignore this case when talking about contraction because the result is no longer a tensor...and that would be considered an invalid operation if you want stay in tensor land...